# Godot: Strange boolean values

Tags: godot

In this script:

```
func _process(delta):
    print(player_city.stats["has_battlemech"])
    if has_it:
        player_city.stats["has_battlemech"] = true
    if not has_it:
        player_city.stats["has_battlemech"] = false
```

I determine whether or not the player "has" the battlemech. This is in the script for the battlemech, by the way. has_it is set when someone clicks the "purchase" button in the store. It contacts a singleton called player_city which has a dictionary which stores all the stats variables in my game.

```
extends StaticBody

var stats = {
    "has_battlemech": false,
    "has_ranged_battlemech": false,
    "has_helicopter": false
}
```

City code

```
func _on_Purchase_pressed():
    if camera_in_first_spot:
        slot_1.has_it = true
    if camera_in_second_spot:
        slot_2.has_it = true
    if camera_in_third_spot:
        slot_3.has_it = true
    if camera_in_fourth_spot:
        slot_4.has_it = true
```

Market code

Now when I run this, the debug print section of the first code snippet is telling me that every frame the value of has_battlemech is
true
false
true
false
true
false
true
false
You get the idea. I have no idea why this is happening, but am probably missing something obvious. Help would be greatly appreciated.
Code for camera placement:

```
match camera_x:
        -30.0:
            camera_in_first_spot = true
            camera_in_second_spot = false
            camera_in_third_spot = false
            camera_in_fourth_spot = false
        0.0:
            camera_in_first_spot = false
            camera_in_second_spot = true
            camera_in_third_spot = false
            camera_in_fourth_spot = false
        30.0:
            camera_in_first_spot = false
            camera_in_second_spot = false
            camera_in_third_spot = true
            camera_in_fourth_spot = false
        60.0:
            camera_in_first_spot = false
            camera_in_second_spot = false
            camera_in_third_spot = false
            camera_in_fourth_spot = true
```

camera_x is the x value of the camera placement

Comment: Do all four slots contact the same singleton? If so, and if you've purchased some (but not all) of them, then the false ones will still be fighting to set the variable to false every frame.

Comment: Doing this in the `_process` proc is the wrong place.

Comment: The thing is that each different vehicle, be it a battlemech or a helicopter, is contacting the singleton for a different value. The battlemech script says to change has_battlemech, while the helicopter script says to change has_helicopter

Comment: 1. print what are you logging. Don't do `print(player_city.stats["has_battlemech"])` do `prints("has_battlemech =", player_city.stats["has_battlemech"])`. 2. do it *after* you change it, everywhere you change it. I hope it helps you spot the problem, if anything by making you go over the code again. - Now, details: why did you hard code `"has_battlemech"` if you have similar code but with other values (as you claim)? and why did you make the singleton a `StaticBody`? Can multiple `camera_in_*_spot` be true at the same time? Why not set `player_city.stats` on `_on_Purchase_pressed`?

Comment: Ok, so I just found out that the camera_in_first_spot is what I think the root of the problem. When I print it, if the camera is in the first spot, it gives me True False False. All I'm printing is 1 value but it gives me three, two of which are False. The code for the camera placement has been edited into the question